# Link in email sent with Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I have it so that the user can send an email (code below).
This works, but I would like to improve it. There are 2 possibilities:
1. Currently, the url appears as a String. Can it be made to appear as a link in the email?
2. Include an image in the email (mylogo.png) and clicking on the image would go to the url
Is either of these possible?

```
private void sendEmail() {

    final UserInfo userInfo = UserInfo.getInstance();
    final String highScore = userInfo.getCumulativeScore();

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(crashLogFile)); // attach a file
    // EXTRA_EMAIL is the recipient, which in this case we don't know, so leave blank and let user fill in
    //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"Extra Email"});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Super Quiz High Score");
    String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devname.appname";
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My high score in the Super Quiz is now " + highScore + "!\n\n" + url);

    startActivity(createEmailOnlyChooserIntent(intent, "Send via email"));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends completely on the mail client that the receiver uses. If it's gmail, you're out of luck, they don't parse links.